# What Windows networking APIs does WebKit use?

Tags: windows, webkit

It looks like WebKit's Windows implementation is using Winsock and WinINet (judging from the headers in /Source/WebCore/platform/network/win), but is that it? Any other non-trivial networking API dependencies that are worth keeping in mind?

Comment: Reading the proxy settings from control panel perhaps.... What are you really trying to do that makes you want to ask this question?

Comment: Thanks... nothing specific yet, just general research. One application would be to understand the consequences of replacing Internet Explorer embedded via IWebBrowser2 with WebKit - what parts would be maintained via OS updates, and what parts would require rolling out a new WebKit version.